# Does FileInputStream have an internal buffer

Tags: java, performance, file-io

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251062/how-can-i-set-the-file-read-buffer-size-in-perl-to-optimize-it-for-large-files) question includes the following surpising (to me) assertion

> both Java and Perl try quite hard to find a one-size-fits all default buffer size when reading in files

[The Javadoc for `FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) however makes no mention of the class having its own buffer. And why should it, given that there is a [`BufferedInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) class? Do objects of class `FileInputStream` have their own buffer? I realize that the O/S itself will have buffers; I'm not asking about those.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. `FileInputStream` has no buffer but `BufferedInputStream` has a default buffer `8192` bytes

Comment: Looks like a rumour based on a rumour.

Comment: Luke, use the source: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/FileInputStream.java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SO question you mention deals specifically with `InputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader` instead of *Stream classes you talk about. It even mentions the default buffer size  of BufferedReader.

I know it is a long post, but you should read it all instead of forking it to another question after reading its first sentence.

To give you an answer, looking at the link provided by *Matt Ball*, apparently **not**.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, at least in OpenJDK.

However, I don't see anything in its contract that would forbid the existence of such a buffer, as long as it was transparent to the user. It would not make much sense, though, given that `BufferedInputStream` exists for that purpose.