# What is the byte array size in this code? Can I make it more generic?

Tags: java, arrays, io, buffer, byte

I read a tutorial 'Read file in String with BufferedInputStream', and I got a code from here:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/bufferedinputstream/read-file-in-string-with-bufferedinputstream/

The question is this line:
`// byte array to store input
byte[] contents = new byte[1024];`

So, how can I ensure it is 1024 byte? If I have a data with 1025 byte, and my code will break. So, how can I make it more generic? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,It won't break.

Magic is here

```
while ((bytesRead = bin.read(contents)) != -1) {
```

`bin.read(contents))` It will read the next set of `bytes` from the `file`.

Question asked by me : [How the buffer byte array is continuously filling while streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105971/how-the-buffer-byte-array-is-continuously-filling-while-straming)

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you are referring to the array is filled by calling

```
byte[] contents = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead=0;
bytesRead = bin.read(contents));
```

bin.read will see the size of contents and read at most 1024 bytes from the stream.