# Can I make the size of a byte array dynamic?

Tags: java, dynamic, arraylist, arrays, fileoutputstream

I'm using a byte array with the write() method of `OutputStream` to store the data into a file.
For that, I'm initiating the byte array with a predefined size. But I don't want it to take up so much space for every `InputStream` whose size could be much lower than the size of the array. Is it possible to somehow make the array dynamic so that it adjusts its size depending on the size of the `InputStream`?
I have something like this in my code:

```
byte[] b = new byte[20000];
int length;                 
while ((length = in.read(b))!= -1) {
    //writing it to a file
    op.write(b, 0, length);
    k++;
}

in.close();
op.close();
```

Here, `in` is the `InputStream` object and `op` is the `FileOutputStream` object.
I've tried using ArrayLists, but there is no direct method of `FileOutputStream` to write data into an ArrayList, it only accepts `byte[]`.

Comment: Why not `byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];`

Comment: I just used that as dummy size. Actually, I'm using it to save images from the web. So, 1024 would do. But still, most of the images are <<1024. I don't want that extra space for nothing. If it can dynamically adjust its size somehow, that'd be great.

Comment: Yes, It works. See the code I'm posted and I'm able to upload the files >200MB without any problem with that little buffer.

Comment: Alternative approach: [Java NIO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

Comment: @tom NIO really worked! Using byte channel instead of a byte array works well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't on the *output* side at all - it's just that you don't know how big the *input* is.

It's not clear where the `InputStream` is coming from - if the input is being received over the network for example, you may not have any indication of the size beforehand. `InputStream` itself doesn't have any simple way of checking whether the stream has a known length.

Bear in mind that the 20K array here is *only* important while you're copying the data. After that, it can be garbage collected. Do you have any indication that this is actually an issue?

You *could* just reduce the size of the array to (say) 4K or 8K. You'd still be able to handle any size of input, as you're looping over it and copying it in chunks. It just wouldn't be *quite* as efficient in cases where you can read more than that buffer size in one go. The extent of that efficiency difference will be very context-sensitive - only you can measure whether how that code will perform in your real situation - or how important that performance is in terms of time, or how useful it is to save a few thousand bytes which can be garbage collected immediately afterwards anyway.

Comment: That above code works with a little buffer `byte[] bytes = new byte[1024] //`?  Right ?? Am I missing something?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: Yes, which is why I suggested reducing it to 4 or 8K. 1K would clearly work too... it's just another arbitrary size. The cost is in efficiency, with more reads and writes. If you're suggesting 1K is better than 4K, why not 256 bytes instead? Without benchmarking the particular situation, we can't really know what the efficiency difference would be.

Comment: Yes Jon, I'm also suggesting  some smaller size that's it. Got it.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was an efficient way to do the same. Why waste any space at all, no matter how small it is. What if the size of the inputstream exceeds the the size of the byte array?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin The code works with any non-zero size buffer, because of the `while` loop. Wasting a few bytes out of 1024 isn't even worth thinking about, but if it really bugs you, make it 512, 256, 128, ... It's just a space-time tradeoff.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: As I wrote in my answer: "You'd still be able to handle any size of input, as you're looping over it and copying it in chunks." I'm surprised you're even asking though - what did you *expect* the loop to be for? If you really don't want to waste a single byte of memory though, just call the overload of `read()` which reads a single byte at a time. Then you don't even have the overhead of allocating an array. Of course, that overhead is almost certainly insignficant, and I think you're optimizing inappropriately, but if you don't want to waste *any space at all*...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what size the buffer is from the point of view of the code. A fixed size of 8192 is sufficient for most purposes, regardless of the file length. Your code will work with any size greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Simply take some small amount of buffer. It works.

Long back stumbled with this sort of situation and the below piece of code working fine for me.

```
 byte[] b = new byte[1024]; //a little buffer
            int length;                 
            while ((length = in.read(b))!= -1) {
                //writing it to a file
                op.write(b, 0, length);
                k++;
            }

            in.close();
            op.close();
```

Asked and got clarification here long back :[How the buffer byte array is continuously filling while streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105971/how-the-buffer-byte-array-is-continuously-filling-while-streaming)