# how does this code even work?

Tags: java, io

I just started with I/O in java and please excuse me if my doubt is silly but i find it dificult to understand how this code works?
variable c in code below is not incremented then the while loop will never terminate even if there is only one character in inputstream and outputstream will be filled with only one character continuously but this code actually works satisfactorily which i dont understand why?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyBytes {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
        out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
        int c;

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You got the same doubt like me ? :) [How the buffer byte array is continuously filling while streaming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105971/how-the-buffer-byte-array-is-continuously-filling-while-streaming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in.read()` method read one character at a time. Each iteration `one character` is read and assigned to c.

Consider the following character's are present in the `xanadu.txt` file.

```
"ABCDE-1"
```

Note: `-1` meaning of End of File (`-1` is added for illustrate purpose only)

In first iteration

`c=A`    `while-> A!=-1` then true. then continue the while loop and save `c='A'` to `outagain.txt` file.

In Second iteration

`c=B`    `while -> B!=-1` then true. then continue the while loop and save `c='B'` to `outagain.txt` file.

In Third iteration

`c=C`    `while -> C!=-1` then true. then continue the while loop and save `c='C'` to `outagain.txt` file.

In fourth iteration

`c=D`    `while -> D!=-1` then true. then continue the while loop and save `c='D'` to `outagain.txt` file.

In Fifth iteration

`c=E`    `while -> E!=-1` then true. then continue the while loop and save `c='E'` to `outagain.txt` file.

In Sixth iteration

`c=-1`    `while -> -1!=-1` then false. then exit from while loop

Answer (score 4):

From the Java API: "A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file system. What files are available depends on the host environment."

Your character c is being used to "read" bytes from the stream, when there are no more bytes left to read the read() method returns -1 and that will break the loop.

that's what

```
((c = in.read()) != -1)
```

Means, read until the value is -1.

Comment: Why is the variable here an int? Could it be a byte as well?

Comment: Because of the way the read method is specified, i.e, to return an int: public int read() throws IOException

Answer (score 2):

When you use `read ()` method, you actually move the position which you're reading every time until you get to the end of the file. So that's why it works.

Answer (score 0):

The function `read` from a `FileInputStream` object, returns the next byte of data, or `-1` if the end of the file is reached. (it actually returns an `int`)

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29

In your loop, you are doing: `c = in.read()` until `c` equals `-1`. So, at each iteration, `c` contains the next byte. `read` in doing the increment itself.